# unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile

Tags: react-native, android-studio, android-manifest

How to SOlved that error please answer details

unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile

Comment: can you make sure that  classpath `com.android.tools.build:gradle` line is available in your `android / build.gradle` if its not then add this line with proper version

Comment: I tried this way but not working.

Comment: Same for me. I've tried a lot of different things and nothing is sticking just yet.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Dipan check if your `android/build.gradle` has a classpath defined in dependencies.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0") // <- this line

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Comment: Curious if you have any information about the solution here. It's definitely not worked for me, perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Are you getting the same error? Any additional logs?